# JAXB: Dealing the with Root Element

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have different `Response` classes for different Rest calls. But they all deal with the same `Entity`.
Initially I was getting for not telling JaxB about Entity class from Response class. It was resolved by using `@XmlSeeAlso({Entity.class})`. Now I am trying to fix the root element name in `Response` 
class.
**Issue1:**

```
@XmlRootElement(name="?")
@XmlSeeAlso({Entity.class})
public class FindAllResponse 
    extends ListResponse<Entity> 
{
    /**
     * serial version uid
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = xxx;
}
```

Expected response is
`<Response>
  <Entities>
   <Entity></Entity>
  </Entities>
 <Response>` 

How would I add `<Response><Entities>` root to above response class.

**Issue2:**

```
@XmlRootElement(name="?")
@XmlSeeAlso({Entity.class})
public class FindEntityResponse 
    extends Response<JobType> 
{


    @JsonUnwrapped
    public Entity getValue() {
        return super.getValue();
    }

}
```

In this case expected response does not have any root element. Expected Response xml is just start with `<Entity></Entity>`.
Tried using `@XmlTransient` with `@XmlRootElement` for Issue 1 but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your `Entity` class in classes that define the root elements for `Response` and `Entities` respectively.

Something rudimentary like:

```
// this class will represent your Response element and all attributes
@XmlRootElement(name="Response")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Response {
    @XmlElement(name="Entities")
    private Entities myEntities;

    public Response() {
        myEntities = new Entities();
    }

    public Entities getMyEntities() { return myEntities; }
    public void setMyEntities(Entities entities) { this.myEntities = entities; }
}


// this class will represent the collection of Entities
@XmlRootElement(name="Entities")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Entities {
    @XmlElement(name="Entity")
    private List<Entity> entities;

    public Entities() {
        entities = new ArrayList<Entity>();
    }

    public List<Entity> getEntities() { return this.entities; }
    public void setEntities(List<Entity> entities) { this.entities = entities; }
}

// a simple Entity class (I don't know what yours is)
@XmlRootElement(name="Entity")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Entity {
    @XmlAttribute(name="id")
    private String id;

    public Entity() {}
    public Entity(String id) { setId(id); }

    public String getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(String id) { this.id = id; }
}
```

Finally, a simple test:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Response r = new Response();
        Entities e = new Entities();
        e.getEntities().add(new Entity("1"));
        e.getEntities().add(new Entity("2"));
        e.getEntities().add(new Entity("3"));
        r.setMyEntities(e);

        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Response.class);
        Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        m.marshal(r, System.out);
    }
}
```

Produces the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Response>
    <Entities>
        <Entity id="1"/>
        <Entity id="2"/>
        <Entity id="3"/>
    </Entities>
</Response>
```

This should get you closer to what you're after, I think.